Area 51 Proposal: Finance (including Behavioural, Corporate, Public Finance)
This question and Chris W. Rea's comment motivated me to create
 Finance (including Behavioural, Corporate, Public Finance)
Please allow me to advert to it here and advise me if this affronts or afflicts anyone and forgive me.  
It's intended to be more general and catholic, but equally as instructive and useful, as the present finance websites. Moreover, I aspire for it to welcome, appertain to, and assist with subjects and topics esteemed "off-topic" on the current finance websites, and thus to complete any lacunae or rifts in content and coverage.  
Please feel free to contribute, support, and opine on it. I will be grateful for them.
(I can't seem to post this on Meta. Would a moderator please relocate this there?)

belongs on meta

This is a great idea!

Any progress so far?

This would be a great idea and I greatly support it. I don't believe it is a duplicate of the Quantitative Finance SE. Here's a few reasons why:

@LePressentiment is proposing a site for finance professionals, whereas quant SE has always been something else.

Questions from students have been closed time, and time again because of some cavalier view that they are not "professionals". Aren't students part of our academic community, which the about page says to support? These students are our future - and we should invest in them if we want a growing community of professionals! On the other hand, this community seems to welcome cargo cult day traders like this "high-frequency trader" who wants to open a \$50,000 brokerage account, this person who needs to open a \$2,000 brokerage account, this person who wants to carry out "high-frequency trading" on Interactive Brokers, this person who wants to develop algorithms at home (I'm not discriminating against stay-home professionals), this person who is looking for systematic signals to trade, or this person who doesn't even know how to spell "quantitative", or this person who is looking for Rentec's secret sauce.
Professionals have a sense of accountability - something that is severely lacking in quant SE. On this thread, I've seen one of the moderators state publicly that he isn't here to help people. He has since deleted the comment, but it was along the lines of "I'm not going to share formulae that are not publicly known," then turning around to ask another user to share his instead. I don't think that's the attitude that we should take in any SE. If you know the answer but don't want to share, at least don't dangle the carrot.
My observation is corroborated by @statquant, who raises the same points here. 
There is an unprofessional and implicit collusion between users to upvote one another, especially among those with high ratings. Here is one example, where a poor answer (does not actually resolve the problem) was accepted for no apparent reason besides a history of friendship:

The scope of this SE is very poorly defined and is, seemingly, being exploited for personal agenda.

There are users who are obviously not 'quant professionals' and are asking for assistance with when to buy orange juice futures in broad daylight.
There are broad, opinion-based questions all over and no one cares.
Contrast the quality of content in the 2 questions above with this question that got closed immediately again. It's pretty clear that trashy questions are left unmoderated for the sake of increasing the noise. There's negative externality that the community is forced to suffer when one or more moderators have a conflict of interest and are evidently closing questions that may affect their own trading PnL, while keeping those that don't matter.
In a more respectable site, the same question was treated with dignity, with no one complaining about his or her "secret book of signals".
I earlier asked for a list of the best journals and conferences in quantitative finance, and my question was closed for being "too broad/opinion-based". Well, so this question asking for the best journals and conferences in quantitative finance isn't too broad or opinion-based? 

This SE is unsustainable and can't grow organically.

There's good reason why it's still in "beta" mode.
No one raised an alarm that the person who closed my question spends most of his time editing other people's questions for no rhyme or reason. In contrast, a respectable poster with 2,700+ on stackoverflow gets verbally abused. How are we expected to contribute if we see people condemned for the slightest of reasons and others getting away by means of favor or nepotism?
Don't get me wrong, most of our moderators are great and I love you guys, but we should be looking to bring in fresh ideas to renew our community. Those who truly care about this community would have no qualms stepping down for a new wave of talent and domain experts, e.g. 楊祝昇, user2763361, user508, user8, lehalle, user697697, Svisstack, user2303, user1628, and user25064. Until then, I am in support of this new SE proposed by @LePressentiment.



why not integrate behavioral finance into quant SE :)
